# Run code after set really Large String at TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/readScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/readTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

this is sample XML file.

```
ScrollView readScroll = findViewById(R.id.readScrollView);
TextView readTextView = findViewById(R.id.readTextView);
String largeText = So Large Text;    // up to megabytes.

readTextView.setText(largeText);     // So large that it spend some time.
Log.e("amount", readScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount());    // This Code return 0
```

My problem is Log return 0.

I think this is because of Log was executed before `setText()` end this work. So I tried to use thread and use `Thread.join()`, it doesn't work.

I already checked "Is `getMaxScrollAmount()` method run properly?" with onClickListener, This method run properly and return 1280.

How to run `Log.e("amount", readScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount());` this code after completely end setText Code??

Comment: Can someone edit this question to properly? Sorry to I'm not fluent in English.

Comment: Try adding a TextWatcher to the TextView

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you write this comment at the answer? I'll try and check your answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried it, therefore I'm leaving as a comment

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, then I'll comment if it works.

Comment: @cricket_007 But it doesn't work... Try after, before, onTextChanged. It doesn't work at all... Log return 0.

Comment: call `readScrollView.post(runnable)` and log the value of `getMaxScrollAmount()` inside that `runnable`

Comment: @pskink I'll try it and comment later. Thanks!

Comment: @pskink ????? WHY IT WORKS???? Can you explain me at answer..? I found post method in the Android developer, but I can't understand why it works. `The runnable will be run on the user interface thread` what is this explain?

Comment: because `View#post` uses `Handler#post` method internally, read more about `android.os.Handler` and how it is used with `Looper` and `MessageQueue`

Comment: @pskink Ok, Can you write your comment as the answer? I'll check your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
mScrollView = findViewById(R.id.content_scroll);
mContentTxt = findViewById(R.id.content_txt);

mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        // MaxScrollAmount return non-zero
        int maxScrollAmount = mScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount();
    }
});

mContentTxt.setText("Long string here");
```

Basically, you listen to the `ScrollViewer` layout changed, which is called after its child views do something to its size. Register the event right before `setText` and unregister on its first called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code.

```
readFile(path)
readScroll.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        readScroll.setScrollY(process);
    }
});
```

then I can run `readScroll.setScrollY(process);` after completely ended `readFile(path)`.